# how to check all character in a string is lowercase using java

Tags: java, regex

I tried like this but it outputs false,Please help me

```
String inputString1 = "dfgh";// but not dFgH
String regex = "[a-z]";
boolean result;

Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(inputString1);
result = matcher1.matches();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: by 'small' he most probably means small letters or 'lowercase' letters

Comment: Please make sure to comment when you are giving negative reputation , because I don't know why you are doing that.I typed "small" instead of "lowercase".

Comment: Really, the downvotes were totally uncalled-for. Clear question, with the code OP has tried (which is BTW clean, compiles and runs), clear-cut answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your solution is nearly correct. The regex must say `"[a-z]+"`—include a quantifier, which means that you are not matching a single character, but one or more lowercase characters. Note that the uber-correct solution, which matches **any** lowercase char in Unicode, and not only those from the English alphabet, is this:

```
"\\p{javaLowerCase}+"
```

Additionally note that you can achieve this with much less code:

```
System.out.println(input.matches("\\p{javaLowerCase}*"));
```

(here I am alternatively using the * quantifier, which means zero or more. Choose according to the desired semantics.)

Answer (score 5):

you are almost there, except that you are only checking for one character.

```
String regex = "[a-z]+";
```

the above regex would check if the input string would contain any number of characters from `a` to `z`

[read about how to use Quantifiers in regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern :

```
String regex = "[a-z]*";
```

Your current pattern only works if the tested string is one char only.

Note that it does exactly what it looks like : it doesn't really test if the string is in lowercase but if it doesn't contain chars outside `[a-z]`. This means it returns false for lowercase strings like `"àbcd"`. A correct solution in a Unicode world would be to use the [Character.isLowercase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase%28char%29) function and loop over the string.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're not using English. Considering that we'll get non-english users coming in here too and trying to see if "ålphåbet" matches and get a no, this answer is not entirely correct.

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit Yes. But I infered from the question ("[a-z]") that OP is only interested in those characters.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
^[a-z]+$
```

`^` is the start of string

`$` is the end of string

`[a-z]+` matches 1 to many small characters

You need to use quantifies like `*` which matches 0 to many chars,`+` which matches 1 to many chars..They would matches 0 or 1 to many times of the preceding character or range

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a regular expression ?

```
String inputString1 = "dfgh";// but not dFgH
boolean result = inputString1.toLowerCase().equals( inputString1 );
```

Comment: For short strings this is perfectly fine; for longer ones its O(n) space requirement starts to show.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agreed but there was nothing specified in the question. If it was just for the simple case as shown in the code snippet, I prefer the readability of this to a regular expression

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder, to a beginner it may be a surprising approach. If I went for non-regex, I'd write a loop involving `Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i))`. That's both fully explicit and top-performant.